# Julia Plot Pane

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, plots.jl

VSCode used to create plots from Plots.jl in Julia into a separate pane.  For some reason it now plots in the same pane as the editor and covers the code making it difficult to tie the code and the graph together.  What setting did I inadvertently change (I didn't think I changed any of them honestly) that results in the change of VS Code's behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Tried the @antonio Parrella 's suggestion but it still doesn't work. Julia on VS Code is still opening a separate pane for the plot that covers the editor rather than displaying it side by side with the editor.

Example of code :
`using Plots, Random`
`plot(1:5, rand(5))`

Julia VS Code Version:
Version: 1.63.2 (user setup)
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:40:02.816Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000

Answer (score 0):

Settings(Ctrl + ,) > Workbench > Editor: Reveal If Open.

Then tick the box. Vscode turned this off by defult in the new update.